# Rails: Partial object loading in rails server but not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, partials

I am trying to render a partial for an object called 'flag' in the `show.html.erb` file for an object called 'team'.
However, the partial for assigned and raised flags for a team does not render.

I am running into issues as this is a complicated association.
A flag can be raised by one team but assigned to another. This is referenced to by using a `assignedto_id` and a `raisedby_id`. These IDs are the `team_id` on the creation of the flag object. Both are belongs_to associations.
A team can then have many flags raised to them and many flags assigned to them. I wish to display the flags assigned and raised to the team.

How can I get this to render? Does anything have to be added to the `teams_controller.rb` file?

Please see the code below.

Flag.rb

```
class Flag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :raisedby, :class_name => 'Team'
  belongs_to :assignedto, :class_name => 'Team'
  belongs_to :user

  enum priority: [:high, :medium, :low]
  enum status: [:raised, :open, :closed, :cancelled]
  validate :check_assigned_and_raised

def check_assigned_and_raised
  errors.add(:assignedto_id, " error has occurred. The assigned team can not be the same as team who is raising the flag.") if assignedto_id == raisedby_id
end

end
```

Team.rb

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :assignedFlags, -> {where 'assignedto_id = "team_id"'}, :class_name => 'Flag', :foreign_key => 'assignedto_id'
  has_many :raisedFlags, -> {where 'raisedby_id = "team_id"'}, :class_name => 'Flag', :foreign_key => 'raisedby_id'

end
```

teams/show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <br>
  <%= @team.name %>
</p>
<p>
  <br>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <br>
  <%= @team.description %>
</p>
<br>
<strong>Users:</strong>
 <p>
  <% @team.users.each do |user| %>
  <%= render partial: 'users/user', locals: { user: user } %>
  <% end %>
  </p>
  <br>
  <strong>Assigned Flags:</strong>
    <p>
  <% @team.assignedFlags.each do |flag| %>
  <%= render partial: 'flags/flag', locals: { flag: flag } %>
  <% end %>
  </p>

    <br>
  <strong>Raised Flags:</strong>
    <p>
  <% @team.raisedFlags.each do |flag| %>
  <%= render partial: 'flags/flag', locals: { flag: flag } %>
  <% end %>
  </p>
 <br>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_team_path(@team) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', teams_path %>
```

_flags.html.erb

```
<div>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @flag.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @flag.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Priority:</strong>
  <%= @flag.priority %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Status:</strong>
  <%= @flag.status %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Raisedby:</strong>
  <%= @flag.raisedby.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Assignedto:</strong>
  <%= @flag.assignedto.name  %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Created By:</strong>
  <%= @flag.user.name if @flag.user  %>
  <%= @flag.user.surname if @flag.user  %>
</p>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_flag_path(@flag) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', flags_path %>

</div>
```

Rails server result

```
Team Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering teams/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."team_id" = ?  [["team_id", 1]]
  Rendered users/_user.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered users/_user.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Flag Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "flags".* FROM "flags" WHERE "flags"."assignedto_id" = ? AND (assignedto_id = "team_id")  [["assignedto_id", 1]]
  Flag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "flags".* FROM "flags" WHERE "flags"."raisedby_id" = ? AND (raisedby_id = "team_id")  [["raisedby_id", 1]]
  Rendered teams/show.html.erb within layouts/application (12.3ms)
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 138ms (Views: 129.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

Comment: What do you get in `@team.assignedFlags` ? @team should have valid object

Comment: @Vishal A team has flags assigned to it and a team can raise flags, this is relating to the one object - 'flag'. So '@team.assignedFlags' should display the flags that are assigned to the team being showed.

Comment: you can get `@team.assignedFlags` and  `@team.raisedFlags` you just need to display them, whats issue in that ? what is your question ?

Comment: @Vishal - they are not displaying when I run the rails server, and I have both in the teams/show.html.erb above

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not showing because you need to use `flag` instead of @flag, also optimized your code please check

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= flag.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= flag.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Priority:</strong>
  <%= flag.priority %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Status:</strong>
  <%= flag.status %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Raisedby:</strong>
  <%= flag.raisedby.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Assignedto:</strong>
  <%= flag.assignedto.name  %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Created By:</strong>
  <%= flag.user&.name   %>
  <%= flag.user&.surname  %>
</p>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_flag_path(flag) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', flags_path %>

</div>
```

Comment: A very silly mistake on my part!! Thank you for all your help

Comment: I can't upvote yet so just leaving a comment for now! Once I can, I will certainly upvote. Thanks again.

Comment: @EvaB11 Okay sure, will wait ;)